# What is the name for a blackboard eraser?

Tags: words, word-requests

I found the term 消しゴム but the definition refers to a pencil eraser. Is there a name for a blackboard eraser? Thank you.

https://jisho.org/word/%E6%B6%88%E3%81%97%E3%82%B4%E3%83%A0

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be solved by a simple dictionary search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「黒板消{こくばんけ}し」 would be just about the only term ever used.

Comment: yes, this is one word I hear every weekday :P

Comment: So, it's OK to ask questions that can be answered with a simple dictionary search now? Up until now anyone that did that got shut down right quick...

Comment: I was going to say.... it didn't seem like a question that needed asking... but as asked, it meets the minimum requirements of "having shown research effort". So... besides, JACK normally asks questions with value, perhaps he's earned goodwill.

Comment: Nothing against JACK mind you, but when I went to that same jisho.org and typed in "eraser" 黒板消し came up, just had to scroll down a little... eow.alc.co.jp too. Would have thought this constituted not showing research effort.

Comment: Especially since if you search "blackboard eraser" specifically it comes up.

Comment: Why are there 2 terms? https://jisho.org/search/blackboard%20eraser

Comment: ^ 「同義語」(synonyms) ですかね。。　`現在では、「黒板消し」という言い方が一般的です。ですが、地域によっては「黒板ふき」もある程度使われています。` `「黒板消し」は「黒板ふき」よりも新しいことばで、近年広まりつつある言い方です。... 「黒板消し」は、西日本で生まれて全国に広がったと言われています。... 一方「黒板ふき」は、東日本の一部にはまだよく使うところも見られます。` https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/term/168.html